# updating json object using java

Tags: java, updates, json

Let i've an `JSON` Object like as shown below

```
{"Name":"Manu","Age":"25","Address":""}
```

**Updation**

Read the json object and need to update the address field like as given below

```
 {"Name":"Manu","Age":"25","Address":"XXXX"}
```

can anyone please tell me how to update the Address details in the `JSON` using `java`

My code

```
JSONObject rec = new JSONObject(data);
String name = rec.getString("Name");
String age  = rec.getString("Age"); 
String add  = rec.getString("Address");
```

now how to add some information to the address field

**Update 1**

```
String jsonstring="{Name:Manu,Age:25,Address:''}";
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONObject childobject=object.getJSONObject("Address");

JSONObject modifiedjson=new JSONObject();
modifiedjson.put("type",childobject.get("type"));
modifiedjson.put("value","newvalue");
```

**Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Address"] is not a JSONObject.
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:557)
    at kotouch.Sample.main(Sample.java:59)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Please explain what update a Json object means for you. Read the Json, add some information and write it back out or what?

Comment: You have to be a little more specific in regard to the steps you need.

Comment: after reading the json object and i need to update the address field.

Comment: I don't see what is unclear with the error message and all.

Comment: (you do see there is no type in you address field, which is a string and not a json object, right ?)

Comment: This: "{Name:Manu,Age:25,Address:''}"; is not a json string. This one is json: "{\"Name\":\"Manu\",\"Age\":25,\"Address\":\"\"}"

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON and call the particular Key needs to be updated and set the value for the key.
Please be more specific.

Create a new JSON Object

```
private JSONObject Data = new JSONObject;

public Test(){

try {

Data.put("address", username);
    }

catch (JSONException e) {

  // TODO Auto-generated catch block

  e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [JsonObject class](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) it is immutable

So i believe you have to duplicate the object and change the value like this:

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONObject childobject=object.getJSONObject("XXXX");

JSONObject modifiedjson=new JSONObject();
modifiedjson.put("type",childobject.get("type"));
modifiedjson.put("value","newvalue");  // Add new value of XXXX here
```

Comment: i'm getting exception..............when i tried that ......see my update

Comment: What is your exception? Please update the question.

Comment: simply using http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html#isNull(java.lang.String) should cover that case.

Comment: sir why i'm getting that exception.......;

Comment: Your address field is empty, if it has no value it should be null or non-existing.

Comment: i 've put some values in address field still its giving the same exception

Comment: How do you set the data string? when creating a string with qoutation signs you need to use backslash. I would suggest that you print to make sure that your string really are correct.