# How do i modify or update an existing json object?

Tags: java, json

I have generated a json string based on user input from a file as follows

```
[{"id":1,"variableName":"x1","lowerInfinity":"false","upperInfinity":"true","type":"integer"},{"id":2,"variableName":"x2","lowerInfinity":"true","upperInfinity":"true","type":"integer"}]
```

I get the input string and generate json string as follows

```
 JSONArray JsonData = new JSONArray();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("---");
 while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {   
   if(some condition)
      JSONObject DataObj = new JSONObject();
      DataObj.put("id","1");
      ....
      ...
    }
    JsonData.add(DataObj);
  }
```

Now i am not sure how to update the values of this json object outside the if loop.For instance if i want to add a new field say

```
 JSONArray JsonData = new JSONArray();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("---");
 while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {   
   if(some condition)
      JSONObject DataObj = new JSONObject();
      DataObj.put("id","1");
      ....
      ...
    }
    DataObj.put("isActive","true");
    JsonData.add(DataObj);
  }
```

then i get the output string as follows

```
[{"id":1,"variableName":"x1","lowerInfinity":"false","upperInfinity":"true","type":"integer"},{"id":2,"variableName":"x2","lowerInfinity":"true","upperInfinity":"true","type":"integer"},{"isActive":"true"}]
```

but i want the json string to be like

```
[{"id":1,"variableName":"x1","lowerInfinity":"false","upperInfinity":"true","type":"integer","isActive":"true"},{"id":2,"variableName":"x2","lowerInfinity":"true","upperInfinity":"true","type":"integer","isActive":"true"}]
```

Even if i add the json object to json array after the while loop i dont get the desired output.Not sure if i am doing it in a wrong way...any help plz....

Comment: Take a look at this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786126/updating-json-object-using-java

Answer (score 0):

Try create `JSONObject DataObj = new JSONObject();` above the if conditions

```
JSONArray JsonData = new JSONArray();
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("---");
 while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {  
   JSONObject DataObj = new JSONObject();

   if(some condition)

      DataObj.put("id","1");
      ....
      ...
    }
    DataObj.put("isActive","true");
    JsonData.add(DataObj);
  }
```